# Mockito: why private variable is not load in mock class?

Tags: java, spring, mockito

```
public class Manager {
    private static url = SomeService.get();
    public void method() {
        ....
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ManagerTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Manager manager = new Manager();
    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
         manager.method();
    }
}
```

When I tried to InjectMock `Manager` class, I found the static variable `url` is null and it not initialized in `testMethod()`. Anyone let me know where I did it wrong?

Comment: `private static url = SomeService.get();` dont have any data type. what would be it's data type of your variable `url`?

Comment: Using Mockito, you will have provide the mocking behaviour while accessing the properties. In case of static variables  you can make use of PowerMock.

Comment: @LKTN.25 when I debug code, SomeService.get(); will return a String. I suppose the problem is it never be loaded.

Comment: If you can run debugger, prove your hypothesis by putting breakpoint at the static field initialization, and also in `SomeService.get()`.  It is meaningless to "guess" it is not loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Mockito, `@InjectMocks` does not do any magic.  It simply instantiate the annotated System-Under-Test (SUT) in case you haven't instantiate it yourself, and call corresponding setters to inject the mocks into the SUT.

Go back to your code, there is no way Mockito can jump in to change the behavior of your `private static final SomeUrl url = SomeService.get();`.  It is simply your real `SomeService.get()` is return `null`.

There are surely ways to workaround it (by using Powermock, or other mocking lib like JMockIt, etc).  The biggest problem here is your code is not written to be easily testable.  Try do some refactoring like:

1. Avoid using `static` in such case.
2. Avoid creating dependencies (that you need to mock) inside SUT.  Dependencies should be injected.

So your code will look like

```
public class Manager {
    private SomeUrl url;

    public void setUrl(SomeUrl url) { this.url = url; }

    public void method() {
        doSomethingOnUrl(this.url.getUrlString());
    }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ManagerTest {
    @InjectMocks
    Manager manager = new Manager();

    @Mock
    SomeUrl mockUrl;   // <- This is the mock that will be injected by Mockito

    @Test
    public void testMethod(){
         // Given
         when(mockUrl.getUrlString()).thenReturn("SomeUrl");

         // When
         manager.method();

         // Then
         verify(mockUrl, times(1)).getUrlString();
    }
}
```

Comment: ok. thx. url is just a String and when I debug the code, real SomeService.get() looks like return a String not null. Thanks for your solution. I kind want to know whether it is a good practice to create "SomeUrl" ?

Comment: read some unit testing and Mockito introduction, and understand why we need mocking/stubbing.  The basic idea is to test against SUT and avoid its dependencies' behavior from affecting the tests.  By stubbing you can control the dependencies to behave as you need for a specific test.

Answer (score -2):

yes, that's correct. Since Mock is dynamic proxy, while url is static variable defined in class. Mostly the mock is used to mock expected behaviours(method), so if you want return some url you like, you can use when getUrl method return the url you like. In your scenario, you can return SomeService.get()

Comment: The problem here is nothing to do with dynamic proxy of mock.  There is simply no mocking happening.  `InjectMocks` does not create a proxy for the SUT.